# Failed to serialize user into session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Can register, and prompt invalid username/password but breaks with a Failed to serialize user error when the user succesfully logs in. I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I was trying to figure out how to implement multer and upload profile pictures and it broke x(

routes/user.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/user');

// Register
router.get('/register', function(req, res){
    res.render('register');
});

// Login
router.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.render('login');
});

// Register User
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
    var firstName = req.body.firstName;
    var middleName = req.body.middleName;
    var lastName = req.body.lastName;

    var email = req.body.email;
    var phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;

    // Validation
    req.checkBody('firstName', 'First name is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('lastName', 'Last name is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        res.render('register',{
            errors:errors
        });
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            firstName: firstName,
            middleName: middleName,
            lastName: lastName,
            email:email,
            phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
            password: password
        });

        User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(user);
        });

        req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered and can now login');

        res.redirect('/users/login');
    }
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(email, password, done) {
   User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
        }
    });
   });
  }));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect:'/', failureRedirect:'/users/login',failureFlash: true}),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });

router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();

    req.flash('success_msg', 'You are logged out');

    res.redirect('/users/login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id:{
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String
    },
    middleName: {
        type: String
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: String,
        index:true
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/loginapp');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// Init App
var app = express();

// View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout:'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Express Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

// Passport init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

// Connect Flash
app.use(flash());

// Cloudinary
cloudinary.config({ 
  cloud_name: 'xxxxxxx', 
  api_key: 'xxxxxxxxx', 
  api_secret: 'xxxxxxxxx' 
});

// Global Vars
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// Set Port
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Server started on port '+app.get('port'));
});
```

Error Message:

> Error: Failed to serialize user into session
>       at pass (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\node_modules\pass
>   port\lib\authenticator.js:271:19)
>       at serialized (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\node_module
>   s\passport\lib\authenticator.js:276:7)
>       at C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\routes\users.js:84:3
>       at pass (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\node_modules\pass
>   port\lib\authenticator.js:284:9)
>       at Authenticator.serializeUser (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app
>   \node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:289:5)
>       at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\
>   web\app\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:50:29)
>       at Strategy.strategy.success (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app
>   \node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:235:13)
>       at verified (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\node_modules\
>   passport-local\lib\strategy.js:83:10)
>       at C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\routes\users.js:75:14
>       at C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\models\user.js:55:6
>       at C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\node_modules\bcryptjs\d
>   ist\bcrypt.js:261:17
>       at C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\node_modules\bcryptjs\d
>   ist\bcrypt.js:1198:21
>       at Immediate.next (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\node_mo
>   dules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:1078:21)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:637:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:610:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:582:5) Error: Failed to serialize user into session
>       at pass (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\node_modules\pass
>   port\lib\authenticator.js:271:19)
>       at serialized (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\node_module
>   s\passport\lib\authenticator.js:276:7)
>       at C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\routes\users.js:84:3
>       at pass (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\node_modules\pass
>   port\lib\authenticator.js:284:9)
>       at Authenticator.serializeUser (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app
>   \node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:289:5)
>       at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\
>   web\app\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:50:29)
>       at Strategy.strategy.success (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app
>   \node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:235:13)
>       at verified (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\node_modules\
>   passport-local\lib\strategy.js:83:10)
>       at C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\routes\users.js:75:14
>       at C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\models\user.js:55:6
>       at C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\node_modules\bcryptjs\d
>   ist\bcrypt.js:261:17
>       at C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\node_modules\bcryptjs\d
>   ist\bcrypt.js:1198:21
>       at Immediate.next (C:\Users\Mike\documents\development\web\app\node_mo
>   dules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:1078:21)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:637:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:610:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:582:5)